# Python pandas, reorder a csv file based on a colum and write to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = 'index', ascending = False)
sorted_df.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
```

Index is the name of column with which I have to sort the csv file
However, I get a key error saying index column cannot be found

Before sorting:

```
index;name;result
1;John;Ok
2;Jacob;Ok
6;Philip;Nok
7;Joe;Nok
4;Stanley;Ok
5;Alfred;Ok
3;Jill;Nok
```

Expected result after sorting:

```
index;name;result
1;John;Ok
2;Jacob;Ok
3;Jill;Nok
4;Stanley;Ok
5;Alfred;Ok
6;Philip;Nok
7;Joe;Nok
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to arrange your data properly before asking this question. and what isthe delimiter of your csv file? The default of read_csv is ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas Index is a keyword for the index of a dataframe.
When sorting by indes pandas might be not sure if to use the real index of the dataframe or the column named index.
Same when exporting the dataframe you are telling pandas not to export the dataframe index. But it is not affecting the column index. This might cause your trouble.

Let's take your data in a csv file seperated by semi-colon

```
index;name;result
1;John;Ok
2;Jacob;Ok
6;Philip;Nok
7;Joe;Nok
4;Stanley;Ok
5;Alfred;Ok
```

To show you the difference, I can read it directly with 3 data columns

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aortner/Desktop/todelete.csv",delimiter=';')
print(df)

 index     name result
0      1     John     Ok
1      2    Jacob     Ok
2      6   Philip    Nok
3      7      Joe    Nok
4      4  Stanley     Ok
5      5   Alfred     Ok
```

Or I can use the first column of the csv file as index for the pandas dataframe by specifying the index  `index_col=`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aortner/Desktop/todelete.csv",delimiter=';',index_col="index")
print(df)

          name result
index                
1         John     Ok
2        Jacob     Ok
6       Philip    Nok
7          Joe    Nok
4      Stanley     Ok
5       Alfred     Ok
```

this can be sorted by index

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = 'index', ascending = False)
print(sorted_df)

          name result
index                
7          Joe    Nok
6       Philip    Nok
5       Alfred     Ok
4      Stanley     Ok
2        Jacob     Ok
1         John     Ok
```

and exported without index column

```
sorted_df.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
!cat output.csv

name,result
Joe,Nok
Philip,Nok
Alfred,Ok
Stanley,Ok
Jacob,Ok
John,Ok
```

or with index column

```
sorted_df.to_csv("output.csv", index = True)
!cat output.csv

index,name,result
7,Joe,Nok
6,Philip,Nok
5,Alfred,Ok
4,Stanley,Ok
2,Jacob,Ok
1,John,Ok
```

Hope that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out. I should have added the delimiter and also the ascending has to be True

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter = ";")
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = 'index', ascending = True)
sorted_df.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
```